# I'm having serious problems understanding this particular concept of a "for loop"

Tags: python-3.x

I'm sorry my question might seem dumb, I'm very new to programming in general.
so in the program below, I'm finding it difficult to understand why the expression "translation = translation + g" actually replaces the vowels with g.

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "AEIOUaeiou ":
            translation = translation + "g"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation


print(translate(input("type the word you9 wish to translate: ")))
```

take for instance I have a  code like this

```
translation = "dog"
print(translation + "g")
```

this expression should print out dogg. so why is the "+" sign in the previous program performing a replace instead of an addition?

Comment: because of the presence of if-else block. your code says that if any letter in the phrase is a vowel, replace it with 'g' and if it's not a vowel, then just keep it the same.
your code is going letter by letter and it's only replacing it if the letter is a vowel, otherwise it's keeping it the same.

ps- no question is dumb. dumb is the one who doesn't ask a question they have.

Comment: The "+" sign does not replace, it adds. In the translate function, the string translation is initialized to "", then characters are added one after the other: A "g" is added instead of the original character (variable letter) if letter is a vowel.

Comment: Use a debugger or e.g. https://pythontutor.com/ to step through the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of your `else` condition. The `if` condition is not satisfied so it goes to the `else` part where the value of translation is `""` which is an empty string. Adding `g` with the empty string returns you `g` as simple as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go from the start

The line
`for letter in phrase:` means that every letter in a word will be processed. So if the input string, for example, is 'dog', it will iterate it three times, d, o, and g.

Next, the line

```
if letter in "AEIOUaeiou ":
    translation = translation + "g"
```

means that if a letter is a vowel, you will append a g to the translation, instead of the vowel in the letter. Continuing the example of input 'dog' as a string, when the letter 'o' is processed it will append 'g' to translation.

It seems that you want to append g to the end of the string, this code should work just fine.

```
ddef translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    check_vowel = False
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "AEIOUaeiou ":
            check_vowel = True
        translation = translation + letter
    if check_vowel:
        translation = translation+'g'
    return translation


print(translate(input("type the word you9 wish to translate: ")))
```

The code will check if a vowel is in a string. If it is in a string, then it will change the bool variable check_vowel to True. Then it will append g to the end. By the way, this task could be accomplished easily by using regex

```
import re

input_word = input("type the word you9 wish to translate: ")

if re.search("[aiueoAIUEO]",input_word):
    input_word = input_word+'g'
print(input_word)
```